# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'AxesSubplot'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, type-hinting

When looking at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) of the `pandas` method `.hist()`, it is written that it returns a `matplotlib.AxesSubplot` or `numpy.ndarray`. However when trying to type hint with `hist: matplotlib.AxesSubplot = df.hist()` it doesn't work (cf. error message in the title of the post).

When printing `type()` Python returns: `Out[1]: matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`. Should I type hint my variable `hist` with this (`matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`)?

Answer (score 1):

Lovely question, made me dive into some new stuff I did not know. Here is my understanding of it:

It is not actually a class but a dynamic class created by a class factory, checking the `mro` (like `type(df.hist()).mro()`) of it you can see the whole inheritance.

[image]

Looking at the inheritance of AxesSubplot we see SubplotBase and Axes, so it inherits from both of these but essentially it is an Axes in a Subplot. Based on this I would have gone for `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes` for type hinting.

Here is a good discussing that I derived these results from:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18222

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though, not sure I follow everything, if it is an Axes in a Subplot, why not simply use `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`. I didn't want to use it because of the underscore meaning it's a private class (I might be wrong?), but your suggestion `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes` does call a private class as well?

Comment: I thought the reason you didn't use it is because when you type hint `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` or try to import `from matplotlib.axes._subplots import AxesSubplot` you can't because it is a dynamically generated class and there is no exact reference to that hence your AttributeError that is why I would have used a class it inherits from and carries its properties for type hinting. I understand the hesitation about it being a private class and I think for type hinting it should not be a problem, you are not using that class just pointing to that for more information in your code.

Comment: "Based on this I would have gone for matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes for type hinting." Actually `matplotlib.Axes` works and is recognised (does point to `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes`). So I went for that instead of `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes` which included the "private path".

Comment: I see, glad you found a solution that you are comfortable with!